# Really big cache files

Tags: magento2, cache

I have tons of cached files in var/cache/mage--... folders that are named like this:

BLOCK_EAAA81C2B03F53B9841775345609AD7DFA54C002_168_FINAL_PRICE_LIST_CATEGORY_PAGE_EUR_20210322_1_1_5

The file content has really long list of some policies and then price-box div html at the end.

They are big files and can take for example 100mb of space each. What might generate such files?

Comment: It's Magento `F`ull `P`age `C`ache

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I'm also sure that it's not intended to grow this big. I have many other M2 live installations and their cache folders are 10 times smaller than this 10gb cache monster. So there must be some configuration thing happening here. Just don't know what it is.

Comment: Did you check and compare the same file? I don't think BLOCK_XXX is that big

Comment: Yes that was the file that was 100mb, but the installation has Amasty's Improved Layered Navigation installed so I'm thinking it might cause this. I disabled it's cache yesterday and today it seems that cache folder size is still much smaller. I hope it stays that way.

Comment: The cause was not the Amasty's Improved Layered Navigation or at least that is what they told. Not sure what causes this, but cache folder size is again at 10gb.